# Error al generar APK en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

Al intentar generar el APK me genera el siguiente error:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before 'com.jakewharton:butterknife.**' in line 1 of file 'C:\Users\unicorn\Documents\Proyectos\Domix\app\proguard-rules.pro'
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo proguard-rules.pro ya he puesto las librerias externas, como por ejemplo:

-dontwarn com.jakewharton:butterknife.**

Y en el build.gradle tengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: añadelo como texto, no es muy legible

Comment: Listo, te agregué el error en texto, gracias

Comment: revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33953133/4987172)

Comment: En lugar de imágenes habría sido más útil que pusieras el texto de tu archivo gradle, obviando cualquier información personal que hubiere. Y también tu archivo proguard. Revisa lo que dice el enlace de @ReneLimon y si no lo resuelves con eso comenta.

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a usar la opción `-dontwarn` te aconsejo revises cual es su objetivo:

> `-dontwarn` Especifica no advertir sobre referencias no resueltas y
>   otros problemas importantes en absoluto.

Si no estas usando Butterknife simplemente eliminalo de tu proyecto, si lo estas usando, usa esta configuración:

```
# My Butterknife Configuration
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```